# pytest file structure - where to put repeated code

Tags: python, pytest, playwright

im making regression tests with pytest and playwright. i have a function which i use in both `test_org_admin` and `test_super_admin`, and will use in all tests. i have looked but cant find like a file where all code that is used by many tests should be stored. where should i put this repeated code?

folder structure:

```
tests
--pages
----org_page
----admin_page
--tests
----conftest
----test_org_admin
----test_super_admin
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the Page Object Model Architecture: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/pom

Example of project

```
conftest.py
pom/
--login/
----login_page.py --> In this file we will have all selectors for login page and the basic functions for each element, like fill_user, fill_password, click_login_button etc.
--search/
----search_page.py --> In this file we will have all selectors for search page and the basic functions for each element, like fill_search_bar, click_search_button etc.
tests/
--login/
----test_login.py --> In this file we will use the methods that login_page.py contains like (fill_user, fill_password, click_login_button)
--search/
---- test_search.py --> In this file we will use the methods that login_page.py contains and methods that search_page.py contains (fill_search_bar, click_search_button)
```